# Why was the ATS language dropped from the Computer Language Benchmarks Game?

Tags: benchmarking, dependent-type, ats

Not too long ago the ["ATS" programming language](http://www.ats-lang.org/) was removed from the [Computer Language 
Benchmarks Game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/). You can still [view the old pages](http://web.archive.org/web/20121218042116/http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64/ats.php) via the way back machine.

Why is the ATS programming language no longer included in the Computer Language Benchmarks Game?

Comment: >>I assume we all know why comparing programming language is bogus and unscientific.<< Tell us why you think so.

Comment: There are hardly any cases of papers that doe the same thing. The reason is I think that it is impossible to do a fair comparison. Essentially you can cheet very easily, either intentionally or unintentionally. One unfair thing is to leave out programming languages. Another one is in the selection of the problems, which may or may not favor programming styles (functional vs lowlevel vs oop). In the past a scripting language could not be compared to haskell, because haskell used multiple cores and the scripting was single threaded. Hardware bias (AMD/ARM processors). And many more reasons.

Comment: >>There are hardly any cases of papers that doe the same thing.<< Nonsense. Go look. "Benchmarking implementations of functional languages with ‘Pseudoknot’, a float-intensive benchmark" Journal of Functional Programming / Volume 6 / Issue 04 / July 1996, pp 621-655. "Comparing Parallel Functional Languages: Programming and Performance" Journal Higher-Order and Symbolic Computation archive, Volume 16 Issue 3, September 2003, pp 203-251.

Comment: >>One unfair thing is to leave out programming languages.<< Comparisons simply have nothing to say about language implementations that are not compared. >>Another one is in the selection of the problems<< Comparisons simply have nothing to say about problems that are not compared. >>Hardware bias (AMD/ARM processors).<< Comparisons simply have nothing to say about hardware that was not used.

Comment: >>In the past a scripting language could not be compared to haskell, because haskell used multiple cores and the scripting was single threaded.<< The programs can be forced onto one core and compared. The programs can be compared on multi core and show the deficiency of not being able to use multi core.

Comment: At 1.5k rep you should know that this is not an acceptable question for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to this post](https://alioth.debian.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=14942&forum_id=2965&group_id=100815) by the maintainer:

> Unfortunately, there was no effective way to make sure that contributed ATS programs were comparable to the other programs that had been contributed. There are not enough ATS experts.

Comment: More correctly, that's the answer to why ATS2 was not included. The ATS programs were removed because when ATS2 was released those programs did not work with ATS2; and months later when there was an opportunity to gather new programs for ATS2, I re-assessed how the inclusion of ATS had worked-out.